# Not able to click on menu using Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am not able click on the specific element, which is in the image format. I have tried using available locators i.e `id` and `image` using XPath and remaining locators are same for all remaining menus.

Below is the HTML code. In the below code class locator is same for all other menus. How to automate this type of scenario?

```html
<a href="#" class="nav-link nav-toggle" onclick="OnReportImageClick()">
   <img src="/Images/reports.png">
   <span class="title">Reports</span>
</a>
```

The XPath I have tried is `//*[@id="ReportsView"]`.

Comment: I cannot see id="ReportsView" in your HTML source in the question.....That i got from chrome while copying xpath using chrome .v

Comment: Try the below xpath. "//a[@onclick='OnReportImageClick()']/img"

Comment: Kshetra mohan,i have tried the given xpath but it doesnt work.please find the below error .Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@onclick='OnReportImageClick()']/img"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit:

Comment: hey can you explain little more what exactly you trying to do

Comment: Rao, The exact functionality is as follows.After login to my application,In dashboard if i click on 'reports' it will open new window with its functionality.In that page I need to  click on a menu called reports but i'm not able to click on that i have tried with different xpath and all but it doesnt work.

Comment: This is the HTML Code
<a href="#" class="nav-link nav-toggle" onclick="OnReportImageClick()">
                            <img src="/Images/reports.png">
                            <span class="title">Reports</span>
                        </a>

Comment: @Shridhar -- Could you please check if the element is present inside a frame, if so, do switch to that frame first, then locate the element. If the element is not present inside frame, it could be a sync issue; just add a little wait before finding that element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below xpaths,

```
//a[@class='nav-link nav-toggle']
//span[text()='Reports']
```

Comment: Shanila ,The given Xpath is not working .

Comment: @Sridhar ,as Trevor Pye said use wait statement before locating an element.

Comment: Thanks to everyone ,I have added the window handeld code now it is working fine.Because after switching on to new window i forgot to add window handel code so that is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest locator for you would be the actual text of the menu item, that is "Reports". One way to go about it is to locate the `<span>` element containing said string and then select it's parent.

This XPath should work:
`//span[text()="Reports"]/..`

That will return you the `<a>` parent element.

Comment: @Shanila and lostIncode ,i have used the given xpaths it doesnt work getting the same error .

Comment: @Shridhar that`s weird. As @Trevor Pye says in his answer, are you waiting for the element to be visible? It might be that the DOM is still loading and your element isn't  loaded at the moment you are looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues where I thought I was selecting an object only to find out it has not loaded yet.

Try to wait for the object before selecting it.

[Locating a set of elements by class attribute when class attribute contains multiple values](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/36968/locating-a-set-of-elements-by-class-attribute-when-class-attribute-contains-mult)

Answer (score 0):

Shridhar, the HTML you provided is an `anchor tag`.  Have you tried locating the element via [LinkText](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text) or [PartialLinkText](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-partial-link-text)?  Examples below:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Reports")).click();
```

Or:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Reports")).click();
```

I ask because both of the options above *only work* with `anchor tags`.